# JSON Serialization of external type issue - convert map[string]interface{} item to int

Tags: json, go, marshalling

I want to serialize the type `Dense` of package `gonum.org/v1/gonum/mat`. Because of the fact, that I cannot implement methods for external types, I created a type

```
type DenseEx struct {
    Mtx *mat.Dense
}
```

and implemented `MarshalJSON` method as follows

```
func (d DenseEx) MarshalJSON() ([]byte, error) {
    js := map[string]interface{}{}
    rows, cols := d.Mtx.Dims()
    js["cols"] = cols
    js["rows"] = rows
    fltVals := make([]float64, cols*rows)
    for r := 0; r < rows; r++ {
       for c := 0; c < cols; c++ {
            i := r*cols + c
            fltVals[i] = d.Mtx.At(r, c)
        }
    }
  js["values"] = fltVals
  return json.Marshal(js)
}
```

This works as expected. Now I have issues to unmarshal the structure.

```
func (d DenseEx) UnmarshalJSON(data []byte) error {
    js := map[string]interface{}{}
    err := json.Unmarshal(data, &js)
    if err != nil {
        return err
    }
    intf, ok := js["cols"]
    if !ok {
        return fmt.Errorf("tag 'cols' missing in JSON data")
    }
    var cols, rows int
    cols, ok = intf.(int)
    if !ok {
        return fmt.Errorf("tag 'cols' cannot be converted to int")
    }
    ...
    return nil
}
```

I am not able to convert the value of the tags to its correct type. My test json string is

```
var jsonStrs = []struct {
    str         string
    expected    DenseEx
    description string
}{
    {
        str: "{\"cols\":3,\"rows\":2,\"values\":[6,1,5,2,4,3]}",
        expected: DenseEx{
            Mtx: nil,
        },
        description: "deserialization of a 2x3 matrice",
    },
}
```

and my test code is

```
...
for _, d := range jsonStrs {
    var m DenseEx
    err := m.UnmarshalJSON([]byte(d.str))
...
```

I always get the result

```
matex_test.go:26: FAIL: deserialization of a 2x3 matrice: tag 'cols' cannot be converted to int
```

Any ideas?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Try `intf.(float64)`, the default type into which enconding/json unmarshals json numbers. (as documented here https://golang.org/pkg/encoding/json/#Unmarshal)

Comment: `map[string]interface{}{}` might seem convenient but please define a type with rows, cols and values as fields, it is much simpler.

Comment: @mkopriva: Thanks for the hint to the docu. It fixed it. @Volker: This I want to avoid. Because then I have to define sth like: `type T struct{ rows int cols int values []float}` and afterwards I will have redundant data retension in the `Dense` and `T` structure. Afterwards I only work with the `Dense` structure.

Comment: @mkopriva, do you mind if I wrote proper answer ?

Comment: @mooga nope, go ahead

Comment: Your argumentation agains a type is completely flawed. Why do you think your map[string]interface{}{} behaves differently than an appropriate struct in regards to data retention? Use a struct, even if you do not see the benefit.

Comment: @Volker: I think you don‘t get my point. If it would be possible to write directly a marshalling serialization for the Dense-struct, I would prefer to do so, but unfortunately there is no possibility to do so for external structs. And a struct like type MyDense struct { rows int cols int mtx mat.Dense} will only forward my issue to the next layer. To create a Dense from a slice you need the col and row count. Therefore I have to serialize these information.

Comment: You do not get my point. Your type DenseEx struct { Mtx *mat.Dense } is _perfectly_ fine and I never suggested to change it the slightest. Use that and attach the UnmarshalJSON and MarshalJSON exactly as you did. What I suggest is that _inside_ these two methods you should *not* use `map[string]interface{}` but smth like `type T struct{Rows,Cols int; Values []float64}` .

Comment: In MarshalJSON you populate such a T from `d.Mtx.Dims` and `d.Mtx.At` exactly like you did. Then you serialize this T with a plain encoding/json.Marshal. In the UnmarshalJSON you do it the other way around. This really works and does not lead to the problem you think it does. Really. Just try it out. Of course you cannot put a `mat.Dense` inside such a T but I never suggested this.

Comment: @Volker: Now I got you. Why did you not response as clearly as you do now ;). This is definatly the better approach! Now I got rid of the map[string]interface{} issue and have a much better readable code. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

if you check the [docs](https://golang.org/pkg/encoding/json/#Unmarshal) of Unmarshal. You will find that the know type of Numbers in Unmarshal is `float64`

To unmarshal JSON into an interface value, Unmarshal stores one of these in the interface value:

```
bool, for JSON booleans
float64, for JSON numbers
string, for JSON strings
[]interface{}, for JSON arrays
map[string]interface{}, for JSON objects
nil for JSON null
```

So, when you try to Unmarshal an int you will get it as float 64. One should type assert it first to `float64`  `intf.(float64)` then convert it to `int`

for example :

```
    intf, ok := js["cols"]
    if !ok {
        return fmt.Errorf("tag 'cols' missing in JSON data")
    }
    var cols, rows int

    ucols, ok := intf.(float64)
    if !ok {
        return fmt.Errorf("tag 'cols' cannot be converted to float64")
    } 

    cols = int(ucols)
```